# FOSAuthBundle Register Event onPreAuthorizationProcess never called

Tags: php, symfony, fosoauthserverbundle

I would like to set up event listener on the OAuth in order to log connection failures, and connections.

I registered an event listener in services.yml, defined the EventListener/OAuthEventListener class with a method to trigger when the event is called.

In my API, I just call /oauth/v2/token to login/refresh_token. These calls are handled by fosrestbundle.

My methodes registered are never called.
Does this url never trigger fos_oauth_server.pre_authorization_process event ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The route configuration:

```
<route id="fos_oauth_server_token" path="/oauth/v2/token" methods="GET POST">
    <default key="_controller">fos_oauth_server.controller.token:tokenAction</default>
</route>
```

The controller service:

```
    <service id="fos_oauth_server.controller.token" class="FOS\OAuthServerBundle\Controller\TokenController">
        <argument type="service" id="fos_oauth_server.server" />
    </service>
```

The server service:

```
<parameters>
    <parameter key="fos_oauth_server.server.class">OAuth2\OAuth2</parameter>
</parameters>
<service id="fos_oauth_server.server" class="%fos_oauth_server.server.class%">
    <argument type="service" id="fos_oauth_server.storage" />
    <argument>%fos_oauth_server.server.options%</argument>
</service>
```

The controller method:

```
public function tokenAction(Request $request)
{
    try {
        return $this->server->grantAccessToken($request);
    } catch (OAuth2ServerException $e) {
        return $e->getHttpResponse();
    }
}
```

Assuming you are using the defaults, the controller service for that route is just delegating to the server library. The `pre_authorization` event is called during authorization handled by `/oauth/v2/auth`.

Comment: Ok it's the code in vendor/friendsofsymfony/oauth-server-bundle. I never use /auth, my client (angularjs) always connects with /token. Am I wrong ? And is it possible to redefine tokenAction in order to add event calls ?

Comment: That may be better suited for a separate question. It appears the `/auth` route is intended for form authorization and I believe `/token` is correct.  You can override the controller by declaring the `FOSAuthServerBundle` as a bundle parent as in the symfony documentation, or my recommendation would be to create your own controller and update the `fos_oauth_server.controller.token` parameter to reflect your new controller.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it will help a lot ! :)